# Spring Security

Tags: spring, security

```
users-by-username-query="select username,password, enabled from myTable.users where USERNAME=?"
```

This Security is working fine for me, but Is enabled is mandetory and how Spring Checks for the enable Condition? if I remove enabled then it is giving exception saying required 3 fields, but if I place 4 fields with enabled then it is working, please provide the Complete flow of Authentication.

Comment: Are you asking what _uses_ the `enabled` field?

Answer (score 0):

I have got Answer for my question.

The enabled field in that query is must and should.  Spring uses JdbcDaoImpl class.   It uses loadUsersByUsername(String username) method. In this process Spring assumes two default schemas Users with minimum 3 columns(username,password,enabled)and Authorities  with two columns(username, authority). If you give more data in Query also it will consider only these 3 fields for Authentication.

If You are not interested to provide security with enabled field then hard code it, you can give true, false or 1,0.